# Facebox on Rails not loading external remote link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebox

I'm trying to open an item's link on Facebox, by using the following code:

```
<a href=<%= item.link%> rel="facebox"><%= item.title%></a>
```

It works correctly when the link leads to an image or action within the site, but I'm trying to open an external link, and that doesn't work.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated, thank you.